# Como verificar se minha tabela tem registros relacionados?

Tags: java, jpa, reflexão

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto usando JPA e com vários tipos de relacionamento como OneToMany, ManyToMany, etc. Existe alguma forma de eu checar se uma tabela X por exemplo tem registros relacionados em outra tabela Y ?

Posso usar Reflection mas não vejo essa solução como ideal, inclusive li que pode diminuir a performance da aplicação.

O que acham ?

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Qual a finalidade de você verificar ?

Comment: Oi Douglas, a finalidade seria para mostrar a opção de excluir pra o usuário apenas se aquele registro não tiver nenhuma chave correspondente em outra tabela, ou seja, sem relacionamentos. Entendeu ?